# xCode ios5 How to append to a localized string

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring

I'm trying to figure how to append some parameters to a localized string?

The desired result (in a string) is "TITLE-xxxx ddmmyy".

TITLE is to be localized.

xxxx is a calculated number and ddmmyy is a fixed date format.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `TITLE`, `myDateFormatter` which is a `NSDateFormatter` and `number`, which is an int:

```
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d %@", NSLocalizedString(TITLE, @"comment"), number, [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

Of course you can change `number` to an NSNumber or something if you wish so (change %d to %@ then).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's perfect. I did try to look for a reference like this in the docs, before I wrote the question. But even if I didn't, if anyone gets down voted for asking a question, won't it stop people from asking them? just saying... (Now I'll get another down vote - oh well). :)